# Drawing phasor diagrams when $x$ is the sum of two cosine terms

Tags: homework-and-exercises, waves

If $$x= A\cos(w t) + A\cos(W t),$$ how do I draw a [phasor diagram](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Phasor#Phasor_diagrams) when $t=2$? Do I treat each cosine term as a vector, and then do vector addition? I know I have to differentiate to get the velocity/acceleration parts, but I'm just unsure about dealing with the sum of the two cosine terms.

$w=4\pi$ and $W=5\pi$, by the way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The only thing you have to ensure when using phasors is that the real (or imaginary part, depending on the convention used) part of the phasor reduces to the original entity, i.e. $$Re[\phi]=x$$

And since the real operator is linear, you can easily check that the real part of the sum of individual phasors reproduces your x, as you correctly speculated:

$$\phi' = e^{iwt}+e^{iWt}$$

Now you can omit a common oscillation by dividing by, say, exp(iwt) to get

$$\phi = 1+e^{i(W-w)t}$$

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can do that. But note that the relative angle between the two vectors are changing over time and the diagram at different time points will be different. Therefore it will not be very useful.